# How to reuse CqlSession of Akka persistence plugin in Custom serializer

Tags: java, cassandra, akka, akka-persistence

In Akka i'm creating a custom serializer for my app that sometimes go to cassandra database to fetch something.

To do this a repository is created and then is registered via [`Akka Extension`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/extending.html) to actor system. Then in custom Serializer constructor this repository is fetched from actor system.

The thing is this repository needs to connect to cassandra, which requires a CqlSession. for now I created a new CqlSession with alpakka cassandra to do the job but it is said that `for each application Only one CqlSession should be used`. Now i have 2 CqlSession. One used by akka persistence cassandra and one by this repository used in custom serializer. How can I reuse Akka persistence cassandra CqlSession in this repo so only 1 CqlSession be active in whole application.

Custom Serializer:

```java
public class CustomSerializer extends AsyncSerializerWithStringManifestCS {

   private final CustomSerializerRepo customSerializerRepo;
   public CustomSerializer(ExtendedActorSystem system) {
        super(system);
        this.system = system;
        customSerializerRepo= customSerializerRepoExtension.get(Adapter.toTyped(system)).customSerializerRepo();       
    }

   @Override
    public CompletionStage<byte[]> toBinaryAsyncCS(Object unencryptedPayload) {
        // Uses this repo
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Object> fromBinaryAsyncCS(byte[] bytes, String manifest) {
       // ........
    }
}
```

Repository:

```java
public class CustomSerializerRepo {
   
   private final CassandraSession cassandraSession;
   
   public CustomSerializerRepo (ActorSystem<?> actorSystem) {
       var cassandraSession = CassandraSessionRegistry.get(actorSystem).sessionFor(CassandraSessionSettings.create())
   }

   // go to cassandra and perform operations.
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [Alpakka Cassandra - Custom Session creation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/cassandra.html#custom-session-creation). If I understand well, you should create your own custom [CqlSessionProvider](https://doc.akka.io/api/alpakka/7.0.0/akka/stream/alpakka/cassandra/CqlSessionProvider.html). It says "By default the DefaultSessionProvider is building the Cluster from configuration properties but it is possible to replace the implementation of the SessionProvider to reuse another session or override the Cluster builder with other settings"

Comment: Hi. A custom session provider is not what is needed, but thanks. That page gave me what  was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In custom serializer we have ActorSystem. Akka cassandra persistence plugin under the hood is using alpakka cassandra. We can get `CqlSession` created by `Alpakka Cassandra` via `CassandraSessionRegistry` extension.

```java
var cqlSession = CassandraSessionRegistry
                        .get(system)
                        .sessionFor(CassandraSessionSettings.create())
                        .underlying()
                        .toCompletableFuture()
                        .get()
```

This is the same `CqlSession` used by akka persistence, hence reusing same session for whole application.